# Spring Boot app works in debugger but not as jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've been researching this for hours and can't figure it out. I have a Spring Boot application on Windows. Standard set up: a public login page and then a bunch of authenticated routes. Those routes go to a React Router on the client side - I don't know if that's relevant or not.

The application works like a champ in the Eclipse debugger. I'm trying to deploy as a jar so I call

```
mvnw clean package
java -jar target/[app].jar
```

It runs and I get the login screen. It properly rejects incorrect logins, and everything looks fine. But when I enter proper credentials and it authenticates, it then gets hung up on the home screen with a bunch of "404" errors, as if it can't find any scripts, css, etc. The public login screen has no problem finding them because it shows images and runs scripts OK. The command window shows no additional output.

I'm fairly sure it has something to do with an authentication glitch but why does it work when run from Eclipse but not as a packaged jar?

It's hard to know which snippets to include but I'll start with these. From my POM:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.lmco.energy.web2.WebApplication</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
               </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("admin")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .successHandler(new RoleBasedAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/api/**", "/login")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "/fonts/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
      return new UserDetailsServiceImp();
    };

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new CustomPasswordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }
}
```

Comment: Check you're using the same _exact_ URL in your different tests. You might find that one is missing a trailing slash, and the other isn't. In your browser, have a _close_ look at the URL of failed resources

Comment: On which page it redirects when authentication is successful when you run it from eclipse ??

Comment: @ptomli The URLs look the same. No changes in trailing slashes. 
@ Patel On success it redirects to the root url at /.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out! I hope it helps anyone who struggles with this in the future...

@ptomli was close. Although the urls of the resources returning the 404 errors *were* exactly the same as the urls I used when running the web app from the Eclipse debugger, there were case differences. One in particular, a subfolder named "/ThirdParty" but referenced as "thirdParty" in the url, was causing a ton of errors and leading me to think that *all* of the resources could not be found. While urls are generally case-insensitive, I guess the moral of the story here is that, when they're bundles into a jar, the paths become case-sensitive. The authentication aspect was, in the end, a red-herring.